# avoiding UITapGestureRecognizer in button?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am using UITapGestureRecognizer for double tap.When I double tab on UIButton , it works.but i want to avoid it? any built in method?

Comment: I know it's been a while, but please accept my answer as the correct one ... It has all the votes :-)

Answer (score 12):

You can stop the UITapGestureRecognizer from cancelling other events (such as the tap on your button) by setting the following boolean:

```
[tapRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
```

Answer (score -2):

I recommend watching Session 120 of the [WWDC10 videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/). It is free, and shows you how to avoid unwanted events. There's a lot of useful information in these videos, and best of all, they're free.